# I am trying to delete dbms_jobs in Oracle using sql developer.

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I tried to remove my dbms_jobs in my oracle database using sql developer and they came back. I thought if you broke a job that it would come back but if you remove a job it will disable the job from running. Please help.

Comment: removing a job and disabling it are completely different things - do you want it to 'go away' or for it to temporarily stop running?

Comment: I want it to go away.

Comment: so did you use the 'remove job' context menu item, which will run 'dbms_job.remove(x);' ?

Comment: yes, right clicked on the job and then clicked "remove jobs" and the following week all the jobs had came back.

Comment: assuming you did this as the JOBS owner?

Comment: also, 'broke' jobs do not run unless you FORCE it, I believe, or unless of course you un-break them.

Comment: I did do it as the jobs owner.

Comment: is the job # the same as what it was before you removed it, or does it have a new number?

Comment: Was the database backed up before you removed the job and later restored from that backup?